# Creating precise connections on angled (intersecting) objects

Tags: knife-tool, intersection

I am trying to create precise connections on angled (currently intersecting) objects.

[image: Wooden frame]

I want to remove the green part from object A, the blue parts from object B, and the red part from object C.

I have already tried the shear tool, the knife tool and the boolean difference operator, but with no success. Nothing was really precise on both intersecting objects.

The model can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/t/ZfuQ1RKejTvBy9dr

Comment: Did you give the _Bisect_ tool a try? You can edit the normal and the anchor point of the cutting plane very precisely in the operator dialog.